# Boxplots with 95% Confidence Intervals in R

Tags: r, graphics, boxplot, confidence-interval

I'm trying to generate boxplots in R that display the 95% confidence intervals of the mean but I can't find any way to display this statistic. I typically use ggplot2 for data visualisation in R but I'm open to using another package if necessary. Does anyone have any suggestions on how to do this? Thanks.

Comment: Does this post address your question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21310609/ggplot2-box-whisker-plot-show-95-confidence-intervals-remove-outliers

Comment: no, unfortunately not. no answer actually gives 95% confidence intervals. although one comment provides code for the 5th and 95th percentile, i believe that person mistook confidence intervals for percentiles.

Comment: Boxplots are meant to show distributions of data by percentile (ranked data). Otherwise it's not really a boxplot. Wouldn't it be better to use a line/point graph with 95% CIs?

Comment: This was requested of me—it wasn't my idea—but I believe the notion is to represent both distribution (skewness, outliers, etc.) and confidence intervals around the mean for multiple categories (multiple levels of the independent variable) all in one figure.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an ideia, with normal dist:

```
set.seed(123)
a = cumsum(rnorm(100))
n=length(a)
mm=mean(a)
dd=sd(a)
error <- qnorm(0.975)*dd/sqrt(n)

inf <- mm-error
sup <- mm+error

boxplot(a,col=3)
lines(c(0.75,1.25),c(inf,inf),col=4)
lines(c(0.75,1.25),c(mm,mm),col=2,lwd=2)
lines(c(0.75,1.25),c(sup,sup),col=4)
legend("topleft", c("95% CI", "Mean"), lty=1,col = c(4, 2),bty ="n")
```

[image]